# Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When adding a Google Cloud Endpoint backend to a Android app using the [Google App Engine Java Module Template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints), two classes (amongst other things) are added to the project.

We are then encouraged to modify these classes to our own requirements. So, I decided to delete the model class (MyBean) and the endpoint class (MyEndpoint) and replace them with my own classes. When I tried to rebuild/clean the project, I get the error message:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.    
 There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib:  
 <package-name>.MyEndpoint
```

I looked for a couple of hours for a solution to this problem until I found the cause.So I decided to share it since this question does not even exist on SO (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to `backend\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml`

In the web.xml file, look for the `init-param` and change the parameter value to the new endpoint class you've just added.

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.backend.New-Endpoint-Class-Name</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Rebuild the project and everything should be just fine.

Comment: I get an error Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: connect timed out 
Can you help me with this,I have also posted  a question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830712/appengine-connection-time-out-error.

Comment: Try the answer I just posted for your question.