# Android studio build failing

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle

I'm receiving following error when trying to build project in Android studio:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: Read timed out
```

I've already tried suggestions from this link, but it didn't help.
[Appengine connection time out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830712/appengine-connection-time-out-error)

I'm using Android studio 1.3.1, Java 8u60.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted to Java 8u51, and now it's working.