# Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

all. I've implemented a test GCM app for testing.
Cause I need a server to manage the message.
So I choice the Google Cloud Platform.
Below is the error message I've seen when building.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.38 secs
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
下午 04:12:10: External task execution finished ':backend:assemble'.
```

It seems that i don't have the valid certification.
I try to find this issue on the internet from http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html
Maybe I should add the CA in the path to cacerts.

But I'm confusing that where is the CA of this App?
Could anyone help me to solve this question?

Thanks for your kindly help.
BR
Brian

Comment: Based from this [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599143/errorexecution-failed-for-task-backendappengineendpointsgetclientlibs), error **Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.** can be solved by changing the parameter value of the `init-param` to the new endpoint class you've just added. Also check if there was a [firewall blocking studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830712/appengine-connection-time-out-error) to update new library. Try to disable firewall and see if it works.